# How to use Maven, Spring, Hibernate (JPA) on Netbeans or Eclipse

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

Being extremely very new to Java EE, I am trying to build a rest api with a database layer.

I am using Netbeans 7.2 and Glassfish because they were easy to install on my Mac OSX Lion. From netbeans I open a project with Maven, choosing archetype `weby`. What I am going for is Maven, Spring, and Hibernate with JPA. Also I am using restlet for my Rest API layer. Anyway, the tutorials I find online, along with the book `Spring persistence with Hibernate [electronic resource] / Paul Tepper Fisher and Brian D. Murphy` keep refering to /src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/spring-master.xml. But the project has no such folder. Instead the project has the /main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml and a folder about jdbc connection.

Basically I am stuck. Some questions:

Am I using the correct Maven Archetype? Is there another way to get what I am looking for (using Netbeans or Eclipse on my Mac)?
I don't want to spin around too much, which is why I have not manually added the /src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/spring-master.xml, especially since I am not sure what to put in it.

Others opinions is greatly appreciated.